# E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'IntToStr'

Tags: delphi

Try to print index in popup of showmessage gives an compile time error.

```
[dcc32 Error] Unit.pas(57): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'IntToStr'
```

In my code I am using `ShowMessage(IntToStr(J));`  J is an integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add the `SysUtils` unit to your calling unit's `uses` clause.